# Get original slices of &str in relation to parent String

Tags: string, rust, slice

Let's say I have a `String`, from which I take a slice (`&str`). Is it possible to find out the start and end positions of that slice, just by having the slice itself?

Example:

```
let original_string = String:from("Hello, world!");
let slice: &str = &original_string[0..5];
let slice_indexes = slice.some_function(); // (usize, usize)
println!("{:?}", slice_indexes);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the slice does not keep this information. The only information we have is a pointer to its beginning and its length, not the `String`'s beginning and therefore we can't know how far it is from there.

If you do have the original string, you can do it with O(1) complexity:

```rust
fn get_position(full: &str, part: &str) -> (usize, usize) {
    let start = part.as_ptr() as usize - full.as_ptr() as usize;
    let end = start + part.len();
    (start, end)
}

fn main() {
    let original_string = String::from("Hello, world!");
    let slice: &str = &original_string[0..5];
    let slice_indexes = get_position(&original_string, slice);
    println!("{:?}", slice_indexes);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ce0f9e9bdcd712bc3fd8e160f71e8c78).

Note that this function will not check if the data really originated from this `String`, and will silently give you a wrong result in this case.

Comment: That does the trick, thanks